# Central limit theorem and asympototic normality

Tags: statistics

First, I'm sorry to post this kind of thing, not a mathematical question.
I'm doing proofreading a book and find a contradictory comment from my previous editor.
I tried to find the exactly same theorem and formula to check this but failed
so I'm asking your help to check my correction is right or not (cause now I'm confusing too!).

Here is my correction.
Central limit theorem: $\sqrt{n}(\bar X_n-\mu)=\sqrt{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\mu)$ $ {\buildrel d \over \rightarrow}\ N(0,\sigma^2)$
Asymptotic normality: $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}-\theta) {\buildrel d \over \rightarrow}\ N(0,nVar(\hat{\theta}))$ and $\hat{\theta} {\buildrel a \over \sim}N(\theta, Var(\hat{\theta}))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's wrong, the central limit theorem states:
$$ \sqrt n (\overline X_n - \mu) = \frac 1 {\sqrt n} \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \mu) \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2).   $$
For the asymptotic normality, it is wrong too as you cannot use $\hat \theta$ in the expression of the limit, you should say
$$ \frac{\hat \theta - \theta}{\sqrt{\text{var}(\hat \theta)}} \overset d \longrightarrow \mathcal N(0, 1). $$